# loading an image 150% of its size within fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I am just creating a silly GIF gallery where there is a thumbnail displayed and when clicked the relevant GIF gets loaded and displayed in a fancybox.

The code for the fancybox I have is this:

```
$(".fancyGIF").fancybox({
        arrows: false,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        openSpeed: 150,
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        closeSpeed: 150,
        closeClick: true,
        onStart: function(){
            $("img").width("400");
        },
        helpers: {overlay : null}
    });
```

The `onStart:` is an attempt at getting the image to load bigger than it's original size, as alot of GIFs are very small, I want to load them 150% or 200% than their original size.  How can I do this? I have tried many things :(

EDIT:  After further investigation, It would seem that the onStart function is not working whatsoever, which would explain why I am not getting any results.  I have put `console.log('foobar');` in there and `alert('whipcrackaway');` in there and no results whatsoever.  I cannot work out why.  There are no errors either whatsoever.

Comment: Just an FYI, forcing an image to appear bigger than it is will massively reduce it's quality.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the size with CSS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah I know that, But GIFs arn't amazing quality anyway and I just want them a tiny bit bigger.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, but that would mean changing the CSS for every fancybox on the site (unless I create a whole new specific CSS file and fancybox.js for this one page) which seems very inefficient to me.

Comment: @Joonas nothing :( there is nothing logged in the console when I do that.

Comment: :/ Well.. Deleted my comment cause I got thinking.. What version of fancybox is it? http://fancybox.net/ ( fancybox 1 ) or http://fancyapps.com/ ( fancybox 2 )

Comment: Just give your img a class and you can use $(".imgclass").css('width', '150%'); in your onStart-function. That would not break any other fancybox and do what you want, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Alex I have already tried that and there is no effect.  The image inside the fancybox already has a class but I cannot seem to manipulate it in any way.

Comment: @Chud37 Try checking the CSS with your browser(F12) or inspect element. With that you can see what CSS is applied to your element. Maybe some other class/ID is specifiying the CSS. What is the result if you use the same code as above but with !important?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the CSS but that doesnt seem to help.  What is interesting though Is that I have added an alert('fefe'); to the onStart and it is not showing.  I think the onStart is not firing for some reason :\

Comment: chud, fancybox img has `max-width: 100%;`, so even if you set `width: 150%;`, the max width wont allow it to grow above the `100%`. try: `.fancybox-overlay .fancybox-image { width: 150%; max-width: 150%; }`

Comment: Yes i've seen that.  I think the problem really is that nothing is being done with the `onStart`.  I cannot get any console log, alert boxes, or anything, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, you are using in your code fancybox v2.x API options so I assume that you are using that version, aren't you?

**Second**, if the first assumption is correct, then `onStart` is not a valid fancybox v2.x option but v1.3.x (fancybox v2.x options are new and not compatible with previous versions).

**Third**, you need to make some calculations and modify the size of two elements : the fancybox container AND the image inside of the fancybox container.

So imaging that we are linking to an image that is 150x150px with this link

```
<a class="fancyGIF" href="myGIFimage150x150.gif">open bigger size at 200% (300x300px)</a>
```

... and we want to show it in fancybox with a 200% of the original size for instance, then we will set this custom script with the `beforeShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancyGIF").fancybox({
  beforeShow: function () {
    // set new fancybox width
    var newWidth = this.width * 2;
    // apply new size to img
    $(".fancybox-image").css({
      "width": newWidth,
      "height": "auto"
    });
    // set new values for parent container
    this.width = newWidth;
    this.height = $(".fancybox-image").innerHeight();
  }
});
```

Change the value in `var newWidth = this.width * 2;` to set your wanted size.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EQmSN/)**

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.1.3+ (use at your own risk ;)

Comment: Absolutely Brilliant.  You solved two problems in one.  Thank you so much.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

onStart will run before the content is loaded, so the image is not "there" yet.

First off, I suggest you get the newest version Fancybox 2 (I saw that onStart is a fancybox 1.3 feature): http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Then use the afterLoad callback function:

```js
$(".fancyGIF").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
        current.inner // points to the new content
            .find('img').css({width: '200%'});
    }
});
```

This should blow up all images to twice the size.
You could also set a pixel value, so all images become the same size. Or point to another function to make it conditional:

```js
$(".fancyGIF").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function(current, previous) {
        var $img = current.inner.find('img');
        $img.css({width: normaliseWidth($img)});
    }
});

function normaliseWidth($img) {
    var width = $img.width();
    if (width < 100) { // if smaller then 100px
        return (width * 2) +'px'; // blow up to twice the size
    } else {
        return width +'px';
    }
}
```

--edit--

Use this html

```html
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Animalien-smiley.gif" class="fancyGIF">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Animalien-smiley.gif" alt="alien" />
</a>
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pT7jC/1/
Note that I added a console.log. If you open the developer console, you'll see the contents of "current" logged. This is an object with all kinds of usefull information

Comment: for some reason the current.inner isnt registering/working.  I get unexpected Identifier.

Comment: Make sure you are using the newest fancybox (check link on top of post). And use the HTML I added to the answer, or at least make sure you use a link to point to an image.

Comment: I am afraid your script doesn't do the job. The image you are using is 18x18px so 200% should produce an image of 36x36px, shouldn't it? ... in your jsfiddle the image is resized to 100x100px, which are the min width and height default values of fancybox. Even if you set the min to 16px [see your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pT7jC/2/) the image is not up-scaled and keeps its original size.